# How to catch pinch and stretch gesture events in d3.zoom (d3v4/v5)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

#### Background

I'm building multiple interactions into my d3v5 visualization. Clicking and dragging should let the user pan the svg container. The scroll wheel should translate vertically. Both of those work.

```
svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)).on("wheel.zoom", wheeled);

function zoomed() {
    current_transform = d3.zoomTransform(g);
    current_transform.x += d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX;
    current_transform.y += d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY;
    g.attr("transform", current_transform);
}

function wheeled() {
    current_transform = d3.zoomTransform(g);
    current_transform.y = current_transform.y - d3.event.deltaY;
    g.attr("transform", current_transform);
}
```

#### Question

I'd like to permit the user to use pinch and stretch touch gestures to zoom the svg in the classical sense. What is the analog of `"wheel.zoom"` is for touch gestures? How do I register a callback on the user pinching and stretching on their trackpad or phone?

#### Notes

- Presumably, it might be [these touchstart, touchmove, touchend events](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/4d2f32a3c959f8a20fcd9f2805d76b2f0af4379e/src/zoom.js#L77-L79). But

  ```
  svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)).on("wheel.zoom", wheeled).on("touchstart.zoom", () => console.log('here'));
  ```

  never logs when I pinch & stretch.
- I've seen [this block which accomplishes this in d3v3](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708).

#### Updates

It seems like it might be the case that the pinch gesture is being caught by `"wheel.zoom"` and `d3.event.type == "wheel"` on pinch and stretch. Furthermore, `d3.event.deltaZ == 0` for all these events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out trackpad pinch is emitted as a `wheel.zoom` with `d3.event.ctrlKey` set to True. That's what browsers have agreed to:

https://medium.com/@auchenberg/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript-a2505babb10e

Pretty unintuitive, but there you have it.

Here's my final code:

```
svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)).on("wheel.zoom", wheeled);

transform = d3.zoomTransform(g);
transform.x += margin.left;
transform.y += margin.top;
g.attr("transform", transform);

function zoomed() {
    current_transform = d3.zoomTransform(g);
    current_transform.x += d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX;
    current_transform.y += d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY;
    g.attr("transform", current_transform);
}

function wheeled() {
    current_transform = d3.zoomTransform(g);
    if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
        current_transform.k = current_transform.k - d3.event.deltaY * 0.01;
    } else {
        current_transform.y = current_transform.y - d3.event.deltaY;
    }
    g.attr("transform", current_transform);
}
```